# How to Check if an Email Exist in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, email-validation

I use Python 3 and I want to check if an email address exists before I send an email.

I've tried pip's validate_email package and it doesn't work at all. It returns true for every string that includes '@' in the middle without symbols. Maybe there's another pip package that does work (I saw packages like validate-email-address, email-validator, py3-validate-email, and email-validator)? Or some code to check that with SMTP?

Comment: The only way to truly validate an email address is to send an email and get a response back.

Comment: 100% sure? There's gotta be some way to check before you send.

Comment: No, a well-formed address does not mean there is a mail box that exists for it. puffin-ocelot-banjo-1234567890-fake-fake@google.com is well-formed but not a real address.  Until someone reading this decides to claim it  :)

Comment: There were reliable email validation mechanisms up  until circa 1995. Then the spammers came, and they had to be turned off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `validate_email` doesn't really validate much. You have to enable DNS validation and SMTP validation:

```
validate_email(email, check_mx=True, verify=True, smtp_timeout=60)
```

Comment: Please share complete reference of code or gist reference